# How to create a correct Unity package copy, which will not be replaced when you import?

Tags: unity

I create a "Package 1" consisting of section A (unique) + section B (which will be repeated in all my other packages). This package works correctly is he is alone.

Next, I create a "Package 2" consisting of: section C (unique)  + Section B (from Package 1).

To save time, I replaced the texture maps in the materials belong to old section A parts and replace this part on section C (directly on models in the Mesh.)

I renamed most objects in the scene and in the package as a whole.

I delete all prefabs of «section A» and create prefabs «section C», because they are not pick up name changes. The prefabs of «section B», I left as is.

Now when I import «Package 2» in the scene that already contains the «Package 1», it begins the mess: «Package 1» Files are replaced by «Package 2», even them are named differently.

*How to avoid it?*

I can’t create each scene from scratch, unfortunately it will lead to the insane time-consuming.

Huge thanks for your support!

Comment: I try to simply delete all meta files - but it dont work.

Comment: Can you do this outside of Unity packages? I recently approached something similar, and ended up using file copies for everything instead of packages. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124474/how-to-nest-one-unity-project-into-another

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I try to copy my "Package 1" with meta files, then i can import my "Package 2" without file overwring. Unfortunatly it breaks all connections between my prefabs and my scene.

Comment: Yep, the prefabs refer to the ID found in the meta file. For assets that are the same, but in different packages, you have to ensure their meta files are the same.

Comment: And how i can save my mutual prefab links, but force Unity to add prefab or material as NEW?